# How can I read json from API and write the data to another API using Talend open studio?

Tags: talend

I need to read json data from API1 and post that data to another API using Talend open studio,  what are the components that I have to use? how could the design be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `tRESTClient` to call the first service.  How you dealt with the results would depend on how much manipulation you need yo do with the JSON from service 1 before sending it to Service 2 (there are components to manipulate JSON data like `tExtractJSONFields` and `tWriteJSONField`).  You could use a `tXMLMap` and then call service 2 with another `tRESTClient`.  See screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use tRESTClient, but I get this exception:
[WARN ]: org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils - Default key managers cannot be initialized: Password must not be null
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
Although I already put the username and password.
I am using Talend 6.3

Comment: Please open your question about a specific error as an entirely new question and enter as much info about your job as possible. Then the entire community will have a chance to address it.  thanks